# GitHub locations for JUnit jar files

Tags: java, github, ant, junit4, hamcrest

**Warning: First question**

I am new to GitHub and am trying to write an ant action to compile a simple project (Java) and compile and run a simple test package (using junit-4.1.2 and Hamcrest-core-1.3) alongside. I am omitting the project code in this question as i believe it to be unrelated. However please comment if you should need it and i will either edit the question or make the github repo available.

I have followed the tutorial on writing a build.xml file [Getting started – Ant](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started-%E2%80%93-Ant), and have created the following build.xml file:

```
<project name="EconomyBot" default="test" basedir=".">

<property name="build.dir" location="build"/>
<property name="src.dir" location="src"/>
<property name="bin.dir" location="bin"/>
<property name="testsrc.dir" location="test"/>

<path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="init">
    <tstamp />
    <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="clean" description="remove intermediate files">
    <delete dir="${bin.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}"  classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="true"/>
</target>

<target name="test-compile" depends="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${testsrc.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="test-compile">
    <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="yes" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${testsrc.dir}" includes="**/*Test.java" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>

</project>
```

The repo structure (or important bits) is as follows:

```
project
--> lib
--> src
--> test
--> build.xml
--> project.iml
```

**Problem**

Now, the ant build compiles as needed and runs the tests. but the problem:

In order for this to work, the hamcrest-core-1.3.jar and junit-4.12.jar need to be in the repo alongside. i understand that the ant build needs it to run the tests, but i don't like having it in the project repo. I understand i am telling ant to look for it in the lib folder in the repo in the lines:

```
<path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
</path>
```

Is there another place i can put it, and what is proper way of doing this. If it were on my local machine i could simply create an environment variable to a global libs folder to negate having to have these .jar files in every project, if there something like this on github?

Also as an aside, at the risk of being flagged as to general, any ways in which i could improve my build.xml file would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are a beginner with ant, this is fine.  If you want to try dependency management with it you need to add apache-ivy .  (Using maven or gradle may be much easier though)

Comment: For a first question, this is amazing quality.  I am removing the "stupid" part

Comment: haha thanks, i did try :)

While i am a beginner with Ant, learning the correct way from the get go is always better, i will look into apache-ivy and get back to you

Comment: You might want to consider using Gradle instead, as it has built-in dependency management. As Jayan said, Ivy is the typical solution for this, but I find it a bit cumbersome to use for just one or two jars. You could also just use Ant's `get` task to directly download your dependencies, or as you mentioned, just store them somewhere on your machine outside of the project directory. That would make the script unusable for others, though.